# shortened php if else block

Tags: php

what is the shorted if else block for this. I seen it somewhere before but cant remember it.

```
if (isset($_POST['value')){
 $value = $_POST['value'];
} elseif (isset($_GET['value'])){
 $value = $_GET['value'];
} else {
 $value = '';
}
```

Comment: You could use a ternary but I think it would look worse. I would tend to stick with this, especially if there could be a third `else` (if neither GET nor POST variable is set)

Comment: Ternary gets _extremely_ ugly if you're using more than one else statement, I wouldn't recommend it at all, let alone in this situation.

Comment: use $_REQUEST as $_REQUEST $_GET or $_POST

Comment: @JapanPro OR $_COOKIE (which takes precedence over $_GET and $_POST)

Comment: maybe there is no need for the last else block. I could always do a isset($value) afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to using the $_REQUEST global array instead of checking both $_POST and $_GET? If so, it should be:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['value']))
{
    $value = $_REQUEST['value'];
}else
    $value = '';
```

Or the ternary form:

```
$value = isset($_REQUEST['value']) ? $_REQUEST['value'] : '';
```

Comment: Second one should be request as well?!

Comment: $_REQUEST is dangerous (see http://devlog.info/2010/02/04/why-php-request-array-is-dangerous/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$value = filter_input(FILTER_POST, 'value') ?: filter_input(FILTER_GET, 'value');
```

Or if you have to get multiple variables, do this:

```
$input = $_POST + $_GET + $defaults;
$value = $input['value'];
```

(The [`+` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) does not override existing keys in the left array; it works like `array_merge($defaults, $_GET, $_POST)` in this case.)

Comment: +1 for `filter_input`. Is `?:` really possible? Never seen it used that way. Will that construct return the queried value? Cool.

Comment: Yes, this is the *short ternary operator* (added in PHP 5.3). `a ?: b` is the same as `a ? a : b`.

Comment: A misnomer, no doubt, as it only takes two parameters, making it  definitively *binary* ;)

Comment: whats the need for filer_input()?

Comment: It doesn't trigger a warning if the key is not set. This shortens your if else block, as you asked for ;-)